Two columns switching sides on every page in flowfram
I am working on a template for a student newspaper, and have set up a flowframe that alternates on each page.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{flowfram} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newflowframe*[odd]{0.66\textwidth}{\textheight}{0.34\textwidth}{0pt}[rightframe]
\newflowframe*[even]{0.66\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[leftframe]

\begin{document}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}



However, as soon as I try to add a multicol environment, the alternating behaviour fails. Instead, all filled pages appear on the same side and the last (unfilled) page renders with both flowrames and the text on the other side.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{flowfram} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newflowframe*[odd]{0.66\textwidth}{\textheight}{0.34\textwidth}{0pt}[rightframe]
\newflowframe*[even]{0.66\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}[leftframe]

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}


The end goal is to mix both single and two columns, rendered like in the first image.

Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you really need flowfram for that? Can’t you just set the margins with geometry directly, which also allows for different margins on even and odd pages? You would still be able to place things outside the main text body with negatively shifted boxes for example if needed.

You make a fair point, I will try this approach. Thank you.

Set the twoside option for the article class, then you can use the inner and outer options with geometry to set alternating margins.

if you do want flowfram, I think you will have to give up multicol unless flowfram explicitly says it supports it, I can't imagine it would. that is, unless the author has done something to make it work, I can't see how it could because the two packages would be trying to redesign the layout in totally different ways. if you can manage without flowfram, multicol is likely to give you a smoother ride in terms of bugs and compatibility. (but flowfram is nice for something like a newsletter, to be sure.)
